# How integrate google recaptcha in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recaptcha

template:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

I have 2 separate methods from backend: checkUser, captcha_check.

How create method from frontend to send data to server or perhaps another solution except for combining them into one method?

one post request:

```
methods: {
      checkUser() {
        this.$root.$emit('loading', true);
        return axios.post('auth/signin', {
          user: {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
          },

        }).then(res => { }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help https://itnext.io/how-to-use-google-recaptcha-with-vuejs-7756244400da

Comment: I read this article